# Operations on lines containing one or more keyword in Vim

Tags: vim

If I wish to run the same command on all lines containing a certain keyword I can use the global command, or the vglobal command for lines *not* containing that keyword.

For instance, if I have a text file containing the following:

```
hello world
testing with foo
another test with bar in it
another foo line
last test line
```

`:g/foo/d` deletes all lines containing the word `foo` giving me:

```
hello world
another test with bar in it
last test line
```

Can I use this command to operate on lines containing one or more of multiple words; something along the lines of an OR statement. For example, remove all lines containing the words `foo` OR `bar`, giving me:

```
hello world
last test line
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The global commands take regexes as their inputs. So you just need to use alternation (`\|`) for `or`.

```
:g/foo\|bar/d
```

would delete lines containing "foo" or "bar".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the `\|` operator in the regex. So:

```
:g/foo\|bar/d
```